# Virtual box doesnt have files machine and help tab

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox

This is the second time im asking this question because someone had to close my question for a reason which i still dont understand.

this is the original question https://askubuntu.com/questions/122144/why-is-my-files-machine-help-tab-missing-in-ubuntu-11-10

Most importantly, I cannot access the machine menu that should be there but isnt.
I am using ubuntu 11.10 with Oracle Virtualbox 4.1.10

[image]

The reason why I am asking, is because I would like to run a USB key inside my virtual box,but since I cannot access machine, I can't access the devices manager either.

Just for your information,ive already installed the guest additions.

Comment: Seems ok in the screenshot. What are you missing there?

Answer (score 2):

The original post was closed because from the screenshot it appeared you were opening Ubuntu from Windows.  Basically it is not an Ubuntu problem.  It is a vbox in windows problem and they would be better able to help you at:  https://superuser.com/

That being said, maybe this would help:  https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=47217

Or probably this: Right Ctrl + C

Comment: Im sorry but i made a big mistake in the question,its not the vitural box thats missing the menu on top, its ubuntu 11.10.                                                            Basically i installed ubuntu 11.10 in a oracle VM virtual box, and when im in ubuntu, the menu to open files,machine and help is simply not there, unlike in the picture here http://i.stack.imgur.com/fP9aa.png .Like i said,id like to run my usb key inside of ubuntu.

Comment: So, the link I provided for the virtualbox forums did not help?  It seems that this person had the exact same problem.  And just to clarify things, those are not Ubuntu menus, they are VirtualBox menus attached to the Ubuntu vb window.

Comment: if they are not ubuntu menus,then how do i load a usb into ubuntu ? I know how to load iso images in virtual box,settings/storage/ide controller/... I actually could load a usb before but for some reason the menu disappeared.

Comment: Try typing Right Ctrl + C.  See if that pulls up what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to enable Menu and Status bars

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Customizations MenuBar,StatusBar
```

Use this command to disable Menu and Status bars

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Customizations noMenuBar,noStatusBar
```

Comment: tried it in the ubuntu terminal ,all i get is that VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Customizations MenuBar,StatusBar just repeats itself,nothing happens.I restarted ubuntu just to make sure and it did not work.Thanks though.

Comment: On host or guest?